# I can only append 1 card element from the following Javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I can only append 1 card element from the following Javascript. Please Help.

```js
var gb = document.getElementById('game-board');
var cardCount = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var children = document.createElement('div');

var createCards = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    children.className = 'card';
    gb.appendChild(children);
  };
};

createCards();
```

Comment: Move `var children = document.createElement('div');` into the body of `for` loop

Comment: `cardCount` doesn't seem relevant to the code sample, so you can probably remove that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is attempting to append the same `div` (stored at the `children` variable) to `gb` on every iteration of the loop. Try creating a new element for each iteration instead:

```js
var gb = document.getElementById('game-board');

var createCards = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var children = document.createElement('div');
    children.className = 'card';
    gb.appendChild(children);
  };
};

createCards();
```

```css
.card{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-board" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have only 1 "children" item that you keep moving inside the loop. One way to fix it is to clone it each time before appending:

```
var gb = document.getElementById('game-board');
var cardCount = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var children = document.createElement('div');

var createCards = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    children.className = 'card';
    gb.appendChild(children.cloneNode(true));
  };
};

createCards();
```

Comment: This Works As Well ! Thank you thank you ! i'm learning alot from here. :)